# What is the * operation do?

Tags: python

I am experimenting with a simple python code.

```
import numpy as np

x, y = np.full(5, 5.0), np.full(5, 5.0)
print("{} + {} = {}".format(x, y, x + y))
```

I get this output, which is expected:

```
[5. 5. 5. 5. 5.] + [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.] = [10. 10. 10. 10. 10.]
```

But when I do this:

```
import numpy as np

x, y = np.full(5, 5.0), np.full(5, 5.0)
print("{} + {} = {}".format(*x, y, x + y))
```

I get this output:

```
5.0 + 5.0 = 5.0
```

What does *x do in this case?

Comment: `*` is the so-called splat operator. Googling "Python splat operator" should bring you closer to enlightenment.

Comment: The length of x is longer than 3, which is the total format placements. `*x` is therefore filling in all the spots, extracting each element, in order

Comment: Thanks, learning it now!